# Rsync - detects changes on chmod and chown

Tags: linux, rsync, rsnapshot

I have some backup processes using rsnaphson, himself using rsync.
Some big data files have changed the owner / permissions and are detected as file changes by rsync.

I would like to disable this feature, so for example a file that changed the permissions from 755 to 775 is not recognized as changed by rsync and stays as is in the destination dir.

My rsync call has this options at the moment:

```
-a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded --compress-level=5 --stats
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

You are explicitly telling `rsync` to check the permissions. e.g.:

```
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
```

Get rid of `-a` and tailor your options as needed.

Comment: Hi David, great, thanks a lot. I will test it accept the answer as soon as the test is done.

Comment: FYI: as rsnapshot was using the -a option by default, I had to add the --no-perms --no-owner --no-group

Comment: I figured it was buried somewhere in the rsnapshot scheme, and I apologize, I didn't intend for the answer to sound curt, but looking at it a second time, it could have been worded more diplomatically.

Comment: Hi David, don't worry, the answer is helpful and straight forward.